# Why is my array appearing as never assigned to?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am currently working on a project that involves taking a text file with information in it and storing the values into an array for use in determining if a certain book should be "split" based on its ID.

I have declared a `string` array in the class that is executing the method for this task, and assigning the values from the text file using a `StreamReader.`

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace ElectionsPollBooks
{    
    class dbElections
    {     
        //arrays, ints, for pollbook splits
        string[] as_splitNumbers;
        int i_splitCount;

        public void Process()
        {
            //opens conenction
            OpenConn();
            //Gets the precinct info for later parsing
            GetDistrictInfo();
            //populate splits array
            PopulateSplits();
            //the hard work
            SeperateDataSet();
            CloseConn();
        } 

        //...other methods in here, not related
        private void PopulateSplits()
        {
            //sets the count
            i_splitCount = 0;

            //reads the split file
            StreamReader sr_splits = new StreamReader(@"a\file\path\here\.txt");
            //begin populating the array
            while (sr_splits.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                //split ID
                as_splitNumbers[i_splitCount] = sr_splits.ReadLine();
                i_splitCount = i_splitCount + 1;
            }
            sr_splits.Close();
            sr_splits.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio is telling me at this line:

```
  string[] as_splitNumbers;
```

That:

```
"as_splitNumbers is never assigned to and will always return a null value."
```

When I also run the program, it throws a `NullReferenceException` during the `while` loop.

My question is then, what am I doing wrong when it comes to assigning the `StreamReader` values to the `as_splitNumbers` array? What am I missing in my logic?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to declare a length on the array first.

Comment: string[] as_splitNumbers = new string[SIZE];

Comment: Your array is never declared with a length - Your better bet may be to use a `List<string>` and using the `Add()` method.

Comment: Well that cleared a lot up. All three of the answers are great. I'll look into using `List<string>` as well.

Comment: [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) will return an array of all the lines in a text file without you needing to do any of this.

Comment: @Gary.Taylor717: shouldn't it be `while(!sr_splits.EndOfStream)`? You're skipping lines, when testing for the end of stream with `ReadLine() != null`. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Dennis no, that wasn't what I intended it to be, and you are correct in I needed to change that. Thank you, its been a long day so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initializing your array with a size.

What you could do if you don't know the size is use `List<int>.`

Change

```
string[] as_splitNumbers
```

to

```
List<string> as_SplitNumbers = new List<string>();
```

and your method to:

```
   private void PopulateSplits()
    {
        //sets the count
        i_splitCount = 0;

        //reads the split file
        using(StreamReader sr_splits = new StreamReader(@"a\file\path\here\.txt"))
        {
          //begin populating the array
          while (sr_splits.ReadLine() != null)
          {
              //split ID
              string split = sr_splits.ReadLine();
              as_splitNumbers.Add(split);
              i_splitCount = i_splitCount + 1;
          }
        }
    }
```

If what you're sending it to (`SeperateDataSet();`?) requires an array, you can cast it by using `_asSplitNumbers.ToArray()` later on. `List<T>` just allows you to add without knowing the size.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a List (System.Enumerable).

Because you donn't know the size of the array before reading.

At the declaration of the variable it will means:

```
List<string> as_splitNumbers = new List<string>();
```

in the loop you can simply write

```
as_splitNumbers.Add(sr_splits.ReadLine())
```

and it will work!

Answer (score 1):

Your as_splitNumbers array is never allocated. You need to initialize the array with a size first.

```
string[] as_splitNumbers = new string[SIZE];
```

However, it seems you should just use a List in your case.

```
List<string> as_splitNumbers = new List<string>();
```

Then

```
//split ID
as_splitNumbers.Add(sr_splits.ReadLine());
```